# Override Content on ContentView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to do something i thought would be simple but i havent been able to find the solution yet.
I have a pretty basic custom element for adding a thick border within a frame.

### XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Frame
    x:Class="ResumeApp.CustomElements.BetterFrame"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="OuterFrame"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    OutlineColor="Black">
    <Frame
        x:Name="InnerFrame"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        OutlineColor="Black" />
</Frame>
```

### CodeBehind

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ResumeApp.CustomElements
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Content))]
    public partial class BetterFrame : Frame
    {
        private int _Thickness = 0;

        public int Thickness
        {
            get { return _Thickness; }
            set
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(value); _Thickness = value;
            }
        }

        public float Corner
        {
            get { return InnerFrame.CornerRadius; }
            set
            {
                InnerFrame.CornerRadius = value; OuterFrame.CornerRadius = value;
            }
        }

        public new View Content
        {
            get
            {
//Breakpoint not hit here
                return (View)GetValue(ContentProperty);
            }
            set
            {
//breakpoint not hit here
                SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public Color InnerColor { get { return InnerFrame.BackgroundColor; } set { InnerFrame.BackgroundColor = value; } }
        public Color OuterColor { get { return OuterFrame.BackgroundColor; } set { OuterFrame.BackgroundColor = value; } }
        public new Color BorderColor { get { return InnerFrame.BorderColor; } set { InnerFrame.BorderColor = value; OuterFrame.BorderColor = value; } }

        public BetterFrame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnParentSet()
        {
            base.OnParentSet();

            for (Element Parent = this.Parent; Parent != null; Parent = Parent.Parent)
            {
                try
                {
                    Color background = Parent.GetPropertyIfSet<Color>(BackgroundColorProperty, Color.Transparent);
                    if (background != Color.Transparent && InnerFrame.BackgroundColor != Color.Transparent)
                    {
                        InnerFrame.BackgroundColor = background;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So using the code above when there is no content inside the frame everything looks as expected but once i add content it overwrites the InnerFrame . is there any way of making it so that when i add Content i add it to the InnerFrame instead of the Outter Frame. I added the Content Property to try and catch it being set but i never hit breakpoints set on it so i dont think it is being used.

Comment: Content is actually set from BindableProperty, so breakpoint will never hit, you have to override OnPropertyChanged and compare name to "Content".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding content in another Xaml control will override the inner `Frame`; because added content is a child view of outer `Frame`, and Frame can only own one child view. So the inner `Frame` will be overridden.

```
<local:BetterFrame>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
        <Entry x:Name="myentry2"
                Text="Second Entry" />
    </StackLayout>
</local:BetterFrame>
```

Here it will not show the inner `Frame` :

[image]

Therefore, if you add Content in `BetterFrame` directly, it will display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       x:Name="OuterFrame"
       x:Class="AppEntryTest.BetterFrame"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       OutlineColor="Black">
    <Frame x:Name="InnerFrame"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           OutlineColor="Black">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
            <Entry x:Name="myentry2"
                   Text="Second Entry" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</Frame>
```

The effect :

[image]

=============================Update================================

Create a custom `ContentView` and contain **Outer Frame** and **Inner Frame** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="AppEntryTest.Controls.CustomFrameView">
  <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate >
            <Frame x:Name="FrameExtContainer"
                   Padding="5"
                   HasShadow="False"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   CornerRadius="5"
                   OutlineColor="Black"
                   BorderColor="Black">
                <Frame x:Name="FrameIntContainer"
                       Padding="15"
                       Margin="12"
                       HasShadow="False"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       CornerRadius="5"
                       OutlineColor="Black"
                       BorderColor="Black">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Frame>
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>
```

Now used in another **Xaml** can work:

```
<local:CustomFrameView>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
        <Entry x:Name="myentry3"
                Text="Third Entry" />
    </StackLayout>
</local:CustomFrameView>
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to do this with a custom element though ? i intended to add a couple quality of life features to it ( like having corner radius set both frames radius's as well as renaming the outer padding to margin thickness and have the inner frame default to the background of the parent of the outer frame)

Comment: @DevlinPaddock Hi , I have found a workadround to achieve that by using         `ControlTemplate`  .I will update answer .

Comment: Jiang I really Appreciate this that solves my problem completely. Im going to look into ControlTemplates more.